# Room - Array of String TypeConverter

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

Does anyone has type converter for Array type to be stored in Room database as comma separated list of strings?

Thx for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
 public static class Converter {

    @TypeConverter
    public String fromArray(ArrayList<String> strings) {
        String string = "";
        for(String s : strings) string += (s + ",");

        return string;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public ArrayList<String> toArray(String concatenatedStrings) {
        ArrayList<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<>();

        for(String s : concatenatedStrings.split(",") myStrings.append(s);

        return myStrings;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it works I have only to convert this to Kotlin as I haven't written that I am using Kotlin

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    public String get_string(List<String> str) {
        if (str == null)
            return null;
        StringBuilder pictures = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : str) pictures.append(s).append(",");
        return pictures.toString();
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public List<String> set_string(String str) {
        if (str == null)
            return null;
        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));
    }
}
```